# Query in Open edX about uploading

Tags: html, xml, uploading, edx, openedx

Anyone knows how to add equations e.g (set [a , b) = {x ∈ R a ≤ x < b} ) and limits equations on **open edx**. I'm having a issue in uploading the content like Multiple Choices and Text.

Comment: Openedx slack community can be of help try asking you question there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for course authoring, you can use MathJax for this kind of mathematical equations.

edX Mathjax documentation [here](https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/open-edx-building-and-running-a-course/en/latest/exercises_tools/mathjax.html)

examples [here](http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm)

For your example, You can use this notation.

```
set [a , b] = {x ∈ R a ≤ x < b}

\[ a , b  =  x \in\Bbb R a \le x \lt b \]
```

And you will get this,

[image]